# Parse array of formatted strings into associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, text-parsing

I have this array:

```
array(2) { 
  [0]=> string(5) "[3]:9" 
  [1]=> string(5) "[2]:6" 
}
```

How to convert this array to:

```
array(2) { 
  [3]=> "9" 
  [2]=> "6" 
}
```

Comment: What did this look like before becoming an array? Seems as you have used `explode` prior to this? Post the string if that is true.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with regular match, [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ir2v9)

```
$result = [];
$array = ["[3]:9","[2]:6"];
foreach($array as $v){
    preg_match("/\[(.*)\]:(.*)/",$v,$matches);
    $result[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend parsing the strings with `sscanf()` instead of `preg_match()` because:

1. It does not generate the extra/unneeded fullstring match.
2. Its return array can be returned instead of stored to a reference variable.
3. The pattern is slightly simpler to read.
4. Depending on the placeholders used in the pattern, you can type cast numeric matches as integers (as done below) or floats.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JLSek))

```
$array = ["[3]:9","[2]:6"];
foreach ($array as $v) {
    [$key, $result[$key]] = sscanf($v, '[%d]:%d');
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  3 => 9,
  2 => 6,
)
```

If the keys are not always digits, then use `[%[^]]]:%d` [Demo](https://3v4l.org/OkNqi) as a negated character class to match one or more non-closing-braces.

If values are not always digits, but contain no whitespaces, then use `[%[^]]]:%s` [Demo](https://3v4l.org/UepBd).

If values might contain whitespaces, then the second placeholder will need to use a negated character class with a character guaranteed not to be encountered.